# File Object Serialization

Tags: java, file, serialization, objectoutputstream

I have a client server program where I need to serialize the file object and send it to the client.

At server side:

```
FileInputStream input_file = new FileInputStream(file);
object_output_stream.writeObject(input_file);
```

At client side:

```
FileOutputStream ouput_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
output_file = object_input_stream.readObject();
```

I need to serialize the input_file object and send it to the client. The ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream are Non-Serializable. What would be the best way for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize files - that would imply that the client could read from a file at the server, which would require a complicated protocol that is simply not present in the Java serialization mechanism.

Your best best is to read the data from the file into a byte array, and to then either send the byte array plainly to the client, or to serialize the byte array in the ObjectOutputStream (you would do that if you want to send other objects as well)

You can use apache-commons [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read a file into a `byte[]` easily.

On the server side:

```
FileInputStream input_file = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] input_data = IOUtils.toByteArray(input_file);
object_output_stream.writeObject(input_data);
```

On the client side:

```
FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
byte[] input_data = (byte[]) object_input_stream.readObject();
output_file.write(input_data);
```